# PHP MySQL Form Not Working

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I know how noobish this question is, but I'm really new to PHP and MySQL and I got this code not working...
I'd appreciate if anyone tell me what's the problem:

```
<?php
$hostname = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$database = "lab";
$con = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password, $database);
$error = "";
$success = "";
$pass = false;
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE username='" . $_POST["username"] . "' password=''");
if (!$query || mysqli_num_rows($query) <= 0) {
    $error = "Wrong username or password!";
    $success = "";
} else {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
        $pass = password_verify($_POST["password"], $row["password"]);
    }
    if ($pass) {
        $error = "";
        $success = "Welcome, " . $_POST['username'] . "!";
    }
}
}
?>
<html>
<head>
<title>Lab</title>
<style>
    #error {
        color: red;
    }

    #success {
        color: green;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<fieldset>
<legend>Log into your account</legend>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>">
    <span id="error"><?php echo $error; ?></span>
    <br/>
    <span id="error"><?php echo $success; ?></span>
    <br/>
    Username:
    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username"/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    Password:
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password"/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login"/>
</form>
</fieldset>
</body>
</html>
```

But when I write a right username and a right password, it always shows me the error.

Comment: what's the error showing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
"SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE username='" . $_POST["username"] . "' password=''"
```

This is an invalid query. You shouldn't add `password=''` and even if you had to, you forgot an `and` in your query, so it wouldn't work.

Change the query to this:

```
"SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE username='" . $_POST["username"] . "'"
```

**Please notice that your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. You should not use this code on a public website, until you've fixed your securite hole.**

Answer (score 0):

First of all I noticed this.. is this really you intention... I think this means it will query around only those without password setted.

```
SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE username='" . $_POST["username"] . "' password=''
```

second what do you mean by (im not sure what you are doing at these point..

```
!$query
```

third, you don have password on your database?

```
$password = "";
```

I got this from w3schools and I modified it a bit to suit you needs

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "lab";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql  = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE username='" .       
$_POST["username"] . "'and password=''");

$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    echo "Welcome"
    }
} else {
    echo "Failed to login";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```